# Tomcat / Jetty - Intermittent request not handled

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp, jetty

I am deploying a Java SOAP servlet with Tomcat/Jetty on a Red Hat server. I start a client on another server that sends 5 requests per seconds. I have a read timeout of 10 seconds and requests take an average of 20 milliseconds to be processed.

But sometimes after 1 hour, a request is never answered by the web server. The clients logs a SocketTimeoutException : Read timed out.

- The load average, iowait and memory usage is low on both server.
- I tweaked my garbage collector and pauses time are very low.
- I changed the buffer sizes and it did not help.
- My SOAP messages are only 300-500 characters.
- I tried on another server and it still happened.
- Tomcat/Jetty thread pool is not saturated.
- I tried with Jetty 7, 8 and Tomcat 7.
- I don't see any errors logged by the container.
- I am using Java 7 update 7 on a 64 bit.
- I am using property -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

I looked at the tcpdump with Wireshark and the problem only happens when it is the first request of a TCP connection. The server ACKs all the packets. The problem happens more often when I lower the number of Keep-Alive connections.

It seems that Tomcat / Jetty accepts the connection but then it does not read anything. I tried with a Read timed out of 100 seconds and the problem still happens.

Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Comment: You have to investigate the client side. If the server ACKs the connection requests but the client doesn't see or recognize them, it's more likely that it's a client or a NAT problem. How many requests and how many connections do you serve during that hour? Is there a NAT gateway between them? One client (-IP) or several clients?